# javaslang List of Tuples2 to Map transormation

Tags: functional-programming, vavr

What is the most idiomatic way to transform a `Stream<Tuple2<T,U>>` into a `Map<T,List<U>>` with javaslang 2.1.0-alpha?

```
    // initial stream
    Stream.of(
            Tuple.of("foo", "x"),
            Tuple.of("foo", "y"),
            Tuple.of("bar", "x"),
            Tuple.of("bar", "y"),
            Tuple.of("bar", "z")
    )
```

should become:

```
    // end result
    HashMap.ofEntries(
            Tuple.of("foo", List.of("x","y")),
            Tuple.of("bar", List.of("x","y","z"))
    );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most idiomatic but this is job for `foldLeft`:

```
Stream
   .of(
      Tuple.of("foo", "x"),
      Tuple.of("foo", "y"),
      Tuple.of("bar", "x"),
      Tuple.of("bar", "y"),
      Tuple.of("bar", "z")
   )
   .foldLeft(
      HashMap.empty(), 
      (map, tuple) -> 
         map.put(tuple._1, map.getOrElse(tuple._1, List.empty()).append(tuple._2))
   );
```

Comment: I am learning the API, and missed the fold operations. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

@Opal is right, foldLeft is the way to go in order to create a HashMap from Tuples.

In javaslang 2.1.0-alpha we additionally have **Multimap** to represent Tuples in a Map-like data structure.

```
// = HashMultimap[List]((foo, x), (foo, y), (bar, x), (bar, y), (bar, z))
Multimap<String, String> map =
        HashMultimap.withSeq().ofEntries(
                Tuple.of("foo", "x"),
                Tuple.of("foo", "y"),
                Tuple.of("bar", "x"),
                Tuple.of("bar", "y"),
                Tuple.of("bar", "z")
        );

// = Some(List(x, y))
map.get("foo");
```

(See also [HashMultimap](http://static.javadoc.io/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.1.0-alpha/javaslang/collection/HashMultimap.html) Javadoc)

Depending on how the map is further processed, this might come in handy.

*Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Javaslang*

Comment: Now I know there's another tool in the toolbox. Thanks and congrats on the great library so far.

Comment: Thank you, at your service!